# WCF service delay in IOS

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin

We have a WCF service to retrieve around 100k records. It is taking below 1 minute from the windows/WPF application.but when we consume this service from the Xamarin.IOS,it is taking around 7 minutes.Any ideas why this happened?.or how can we improve the performance?

Comment: Start by measuring where the time goes: is it the transfer of data or the processing afterwards (deserialization)?

Comment: No serialization or deserilization..the delay is between the service call starts and the service call response arrive.

Comment: In WCF this means you have the final objects at this point in time. So they have been deserialized already.This can take time on an embedded device like to iPhone. Use Fiddler, Wireshark etc to see the time used for the network roundtrip.